# How to implement a multi-threaded timer task in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

The Job I am trying to do is to simulate a stop-and-wait ARQ in java.The initial setup is

1. Create a `ServerSocket`.
2. For each of the accepted client , create a new thread for that client with ServerSocket.accept.

Now , the main part what I am basically trying to do.

1. Send a Packet to client. (Or some data to the client)
2. **WAIT 1s BUT IF AN ACKKNOWLEDGEMENT ARRIVES WITHIN THAT TIME BREAK THE WAITING PERIOD AND GO TO THE NEXT LOOP**

   ```
   List<String> frames = frame.getFrames(Server.getData());
   for(int i=0;i<frames.size();++i)
   {
       String currFrame = frames.get(i);
       writer.println(currFrame); // A printwriter for socket
       writer.flush();
       if(reader.readline()) // for 1 sec
       /** 
           Here is what I want to do. I want to keep reading for input upto 1 sec.
           if No input is found after even after 1 sec. Decrement i and go to the 
           start of the loop
      **/

   }
   ```

   The problem here is , this reader being a blocking code will hold until an input is available. But what I want is , if after 1 second reader doesn't find an input , it breaks out of the loop . And we have to notice that this code is in a separate Thread.

So, Is there any neat solution to this problem ?
And [here](https://github.com/tamimcsedu19/ARQImplementation/blob/master/src/dacom/tajo/server/ClientHandlerStopAndWait.java) is the full code.

Comment: Read the documentation of [`Socket.setSoTimeout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)).

Comment: you could also try non-blocking, event-based IO via NIO. that way a timer and a read would just be two different kinds of events.

Answer (score 1):

you need to setSoTimeut:

```
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(somePort);

    Socket incoming = socket.accept();
    incoming.setSoTimeout(1000);
```

Comment: So , I have to catch an exception when the time runs out ? right?